# How to make owner-drawn TreeNode class arrange items like in indented tree?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, tree

So there is a great open source [tutorial on creating TreeNode class](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/11/23/handle-mouse-events-for-a-generic-treenode-class-in-c.aspx). It is great. But I wonder how to change its Arrange function to make it draw [indented](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/indent.html) tree?

Here's the function:

```
// Arrange the node and its children in the allowed area.
// Set xmin to indicate the right edge of our subtree.
// Set ymin to indicate the bottom edge of our subtree.
public void Arrange(Graphics gr, ref float xmin, ref float ymin)
{
    // See how big this node is.
    SizeF my_size = Data.GetSize(gr, MyFont);

    // Recursively arrange our children,
    // allowing room for this node.
    float x = xmin;
    float biggest_ymin = ymin + my_size.Height;
    float subtree_ymin = ymin + my_size.Height + Voffset;
    foreach (TreeNode<T> child in Children)
    {
        // Arrange this child's subtree.
        float child_ymin = subtree_ymin;
        child.Arrange(gr, ref x, ref child_ymin);

        // See if this increases the biggest ymin value.
        if (biggest_ymin < child_ymin) biggest_ymin = child_ymin;

        // Allow room before the next sibling.
        x += Hoffset;
    }

    // Remove the spacing after the last child.
    if (Children.Count > 0) x -= Hoffset;

    // See if this node is wider than the subtree under it.
    float subtree_width = x - xmin;
    if (my_size.Width > subtree_width)
    {
        // Center the subtree under this node.
        // Make the children rearrange themselves
        // moved to center their subtrees.
        x = xmin + (my_size.Width - subtree_width) / 2;
        foreach (TreeNode<T> child in Children)
        {
            // Arrange this child's subtree.
            child.Arrange(gr, ref x, ref subtree_ymin);

            // Allow room before the next sibling.
            x += Hoffset;
        }

        // The subtree's width is this node's width.
        subtree_width = my_size.Width;
    }

    // Set this node's center position.
    Center = new PointF(
        xmin + subtree_width / 2,
        ymin + my_size.Height / 2);

    // Increase xmin to allow room for
    // the subtree before returning.
    xmin += subtree_width;

    // Set the return value for ymin.
    ymin = biggest_ymin;
}
```

How it looks now:

[image]

How indented tree looks like ( image based on [DmitryG s grate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860609/how-to-make-owner-drawn-treenode-class-arrange-items-like-in-indented-tree/7889792#7889792)):

[image]

So.. How do I make it draw the graph in the indented form?

Comment: Why not use the built-in [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) to visualize your tree?

Comment: its main point of owner-drawn=)

Comment: @Kabumbus `its main point of owner-drawn` Is this a homework? Or, are you looking for a subcontractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the TreeNode.Arrange() method for indented tree arrangement.
 
Now it looks like this:

```
public void Arrange(Graphics gr, ref float xmin, ref float ymin) {
    // See how big this node is.
    SizeF my_size = Data.GetSize(gr, MyFont);
    // Recursively arrange our children,
    // allowing room for this node.
    float y = ymin + my_size.Height;
    float biggest_xmin = xmin + my_size.Width;
    float subtree_xmin = xmin + my_size.Width + Hoffset;
    foreach(TreeNode<T> child in Children) {
        // Arrange this child's subtree.
        float child_xmin = subtree_xmin;
        child.Arrange(gr, ref child_xmin, ref y);
        // See if this increases the biggest ymin value.
        if(biggest_xmin < child_xmin) biggest_xmin = child_xmin;
        // Allow room before the next sibling.
        y += Voffset;
    }
    // Remove the spacing after the last child.
    if(Children.Count > 0) y -= Voffset;
    // See if this node is wider than the subtree under it.
    float subtree_height = y - ymin;
    if(my_size.Height > subtree_height) {
        y = ymin + (my_size.Height - subtree_height) / 2;
        foreach(TreeNode<T> child in Children) {
            // Arrange this child's subtree.
            child.Arrange(gr, ref subtree_xmin, ref y);
            y += Voffset;
        }
        subtree_height = my_size.Height;
    }
    // Set this node's center position.
    Center = new PointF(xmin + my_size.Width / 2, ymin + my_size.Height / 2);
    ymin += subtree_height;
    xmin = biggest_xmin;
}
```

Note, that the DrawSubtreLinks() method have also been modified:

```
private void DrawSubtreeLinks(Graphics gr) {
    foreach(TreeNode<T> child in Children) {
        PointF p = new PointF(Center.X, child.Center.Y);
        gr.DrawLine(MyPen, Center, p);
        gr.DrawLine(MyPen, p, child.Center);
        child.DrawSubtreeLinks(gr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, tested, and will receive a  bounty in 5 hours (due to SO awarding time restrictions).

Comment: BTW: here is answer from original TreeNode author http://blog.csharphelper.com/2011/10/25/make-a-generic-treenode-class-that-can-draw-trees-oriented-vertically-or-horizontally-in-c.aspx?results=1

Answer (score 1):

You can render a tree recursively, and keep track of the depth you're at to determine the indent level.

As in:

```
rootNode.RenderTree(0, 0);    // Recursively draw root node at (0,0)
...


void RenderTree(int depth, ref int y)
{
    // Draw this Node at position (depth * indentAmount, y)
    ... whatever you like here to get the style of items that you want...

    depth++;               // Increase indent level (X pos) for all children
    y += thisNode.Height;  // After drawing each item, move down the page

    // Now recurse to draw all children
    foreach (Node childNode in Children)
        childNode.RenderTree(depth, ref y);
}
```

There's a bit more work to do to draw the joining lines (you need to use the depth level to tell you how many lines to draw), but that's essentially it.

Note that we pass y as a `ref` so that each item moves the drawing location down the page sequentially, but we pass depth by value as it is constant for all the children at the same level of the tree.

(Note that this pseudocode is very similar to your Arrange method - just change the name and pass in the Graphics object and it's pretty much a plug-in replacement. I'll leave it up to you to work out how to draw the lines, circles and text for each item, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

The actual indent margins and stuff will take some trial and error, but this should work as a basic pseudo algorithm

Create a class that stores the treeNode, Depth, and PrevSiblingIndex, then use that to populate a single array for all tree nodes.  So when you're done, the index of the node in the array is it's row number(y offset), the depth is it's indent (x offset), and if the PrevSiblingIndex is null, than you just need to connect a line to the parent.  If it's not null, you'll need to connect a line from the current row, up to it's prevSibling.

Answer (score 0):

TreeNodes have a .Level property that you can use to determine how far to indent your node.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.level.aspx